# Using Python Pandas to plot a stock and volume chart on the same chart

Tags: python, pandas, save, subplot

I am trying to plot then save a stock and volume chart using Pandas.  When I run the code it shows both plots but it only saves the second.  Sorry been stuck on it for a while

```
plt.figure()
df_S.MVA_short.plot(label='MVA_Short')
df_S.MVA_long.plot(label='MVA_Long')
df_S.Open.plot(label='Open')

plt.title("BHP", size =20)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, .5))
plt.tight_layout()

plt.figure(2)
df_S.Volume.plot(label='Volume')
plt.savefig('BHP')

plt.title("BHP", size =20)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, .5))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('BHP')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `plt.savefig` to save two different images to the same (one) filename, so the second image you save overwrites the first one.